# SAPUI5 : How to get the index of a row?

Tags: javascript, indexing, row, sapui5

I have a problem, in fact I can't retrieve the index of the row in a table. I tried many things but I haven't found the solution. Here is my code:

```
<script id='TableSuser'>
var oTableSuser = new sap.ui.table.Table({editable:false, width: "400px", visibleRowCount:2});
var oControl = new sap.ui.commons.Button({text : "{suser}",  press : function() {openDialog(oTableSuser.getSelectedIndex());}});
oTableSuser.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "Suser"}), template: oControl, sortProperty: "Button", filterProperty: "Button", name: "password_colonne"}));
oControl = new sap.ui.commons.TextView({text:"{suser_mdp}"});
oTableSuser.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "suser_mdp"}), template: oControl, sortProperty: "suser_mdp", filterProperty: "suser_mdp", visible: false}));

var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
oModel.loadData("suser.php");
oTableSuser.setModel(oModel);
oTableSuser.bindRows("/");

function openDialog(index) {
var currentRowContext = oTableSuser.getContextByIndex(index);
var valeur_suser_mdp = oModel.getProperty("suser_mdp",currentRowContext); 

alert(index);
alert(currentRowContext);
alert(valeur_suser_mdp);
oTableSuser.getColumns()[1].setVisible(true);
};
oTableSuser.placeAt("suser");
</script>
```

I would like to retrieve the index of the row when I call the function *function() {openDialog(**oTableSuser.getSelectedIndex()**);}*

I tried different things and I didn't find how to retrieve the index of the row, I always have "-1"
If someone has an idea I'm interested? :)

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a variable to a template function, which does not work (at the time of rendering, nothing is selected hence -1)

Better have your code like this:

```
var oControl = new sap.ui.commons.Button({
    text  : "{suser}",  
    press : oController.openDialog
});
```

and in your controller, define your `openDialog` method as follows:

```
openDialog: function(oEvent) {
    var tbl   = sap.ui.getCore().byId("id_of_your_table"),
        index = tbl.getSelectedIndex();
}
```

Comment: Then you probably made a typo... any errors in the console?

Answer (score -1):

Probably a bit too late but this might help someone looking for a solution for this.

If you have the id of the table or if you have the table object then you can just do the below to get the selected index.

```
`var table = sap.ui.getCore().byId("you table id");
```

var index = parseInt(table._aSelectedPaths[0].replace('/',''),10)`

OR
if you want to get index on row press event then you can simply do the below in the callback function.

`onRowPress:function(evt)
{
var index = parseInt(evt.getSource()._aSelectedPaths[0].replace('/',''),10);
}`